# Quando tento exibir os valores de um vector aparecem alguns zeros a mais

Tags: c++, vector

Desejo exibir alguns valores do meu vetor, mas antes de exibir os valores estão aparecendo alguns zeros.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  int size_vector, new_value;

  cin >> size_vector;
  vector<int>values(size_vector);

  for(int i = 0; i < size_vector; i++){
    cin >> new_value;
    values.push_back(i);
  }

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++){
    cout << values.at(i) << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos supor que eu informei que desejo 5 elementos, assim `size_vector` será 5.

Na linha

```
vector<int>values(size_vector)
```

Você define um vetor de inteiros de tamanho 5 inicializado com 0. Ou seja, teria algo como:

```
values = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Dentro do seu laço você utiliza o método `push_back` para alterar seu vetor. Vide [documentação](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/):

> Add element at the end
>
> Adds a new element at the end of the vector,
>   after its current last element. The content of val is copied (or
>   moved) to the new element.
>
> This effectively increases the container size by one, which causes an
>   automatic reallocation of the allocated storage space if -and only if-
>   the new vector size surpasses the current vector capacity.

Ou seja, o valor será adicionado ao final do vetor realocando a memória necessária para armazená-lo. Se eu informar os valores de 1 a 5 na entrada, seu vetor ficaria:

```
values = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Que não parece ser o que deseja.

Se quer apenas alterar os valores no vetor você poderá fazer:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size_vector; i++){
    cin >> new_value;
    values.at(i) = new_value;
}
```

Dado que o método `at` pode retornar uma referência. Uma vez que `vector` implementa o operador `[]` que também pode retornar uma referência, fazer `values[i] = new_value` também é possível.

Answer (score 2):

Se você vai adicionar os elementos no vetor não faz sentido inicializá-lo com um tamanho, fazendo desta forma está criando elementos com valor sem definição, estes zeros que está imprimindo (mas poderia nem ser zeros, isto é lixo de memória) e depois imprimindo o que está sendo adicionado. Além disto está adicionando o valor do contador do laço (`i`) e não o valor entrado (`new_value`). Aproveitei e mudei um dos laços e fiz de forma mais idiomática e performática para C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int size_vector, new_value;
    cin >> size_vector;
    vector<int> values;
    for (int i = 0; i < size_vector; i++) {
      cin >> new_value;
      values.push_back(new_value);
    }
    for (auto item : values) cout << item << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/mnhJlk). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/FillVectorcpp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Array/FillVector.cpp).

Por outro lado pode ser que queira inicializar o vetor e não adicionar elementos, aí seria outro código e talvez nem seja ocaso de usar um `vector`, mas não vou mudar isto por não saber os requisitos. Apensar inicializando e preenchendo os dados nos elementos já criados. Eu iria por esse caminho por ser mais simples e mais rápido. Existe uma pequena possibilidade de mudar o algoritmo e criar algum problema se não tomar cuidado já que os elementos estão sendo criados e **devem** ser preenchidos sempre para não ficar com lixo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int size_vector;
    cin >> size_vector;
    vector<int> values(size_vector);
    for (int i = 0; i < size_vector; i++) {
        cin >> values[i];
    }
    for (auto item : values) cout << item << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/rJu6hY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/FillVector2cpp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Array/FillVector2.cpp).

Comment: Não daria até para fazer `cin >> values[i]` ali e remover o `new_value`?

Comment: Sim, daria no segundo, posso fazer